# how to cache video in an ipad?

Tags: ipad, caching, xcode4, video-streaming

Is there any way to cache video of type .mov in an ipad?

I have tried saving recevied data in a file but was not able to play it again as I am saving only data.

Is there any way to convert the recevied data into a playable video file of desired type?

Many Thanks,

Avi